# How to avoid exception There is no row at position in VB.NET

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I have this condition:

```
If IsNothing(ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowData).Item("DATE")) Then
Else
    txtDATE.Text = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowData).Item("DATE")
End If
```

What ever I do it is the same error.
How can I resolve this?

Comment: Well, what is `rowData` and does this number exceed the `ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count` value? Use the debugger to check it. You know that all indexes in .NET start at position 0? So a for-loop runs from 0 to `Rows.Count - 1`.

Comment: rowDate is an Integer. I have a loop that is going until 10 but my data set can sometimes has less than 10 rows.

Comment: @Seasise: then you have already the answer

Comment: I want to create TextBox control dinamically and to set it text from data set but if for 10 row data set doesn't have data just to leave text of the TextBox empty.

Comment: @SeaSide then you just need to count the number of rows in ds.Tables(0).Rows (hint, it has a Count property) and make sure rowData never goes over this value. Say the count is 7, if you need to always create 10 textboxes, you just leave the last 3 textboxes blank, and don't try to access a row for them.

Comment: Use right tool for the job - `DataGridView` You can generate all textboxes by one line `datagridview.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have a loop that is going until 10 but my data set can sometimes has
>   less than 10 rows. I want to create TextBox control dinamically and to
>   set it text from data set but if for 10 row data set doesn't have data
>   just to leave text of the TextBox empty

Then use an `If` to check that condition:

```
For rowData As Int32 = 0 To 10
   ' .....
   If ds.Tables(0).Rows.Count > rowData Then
        Dim dt As Date? = ds.Tables(0).Rows(rowData).Field(Of Date?)("DATE")
        txtDATE.Text = If(dt.HasValue, dt.Value.ToString(), "")
   Else
       txtDATE.Text = ""
   End If
Next
```

I think the column is a nullable date-column(because you're using `IsNothing`). Then i'd prefer using a `Date?`, therefore you can use [`DataRowExtensions.Field`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datarowextensions.field(v=vs.110).aspx) which supports nullable types.

Comment: Great! Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Instead of 10 textboxes you can use only one `DataGridView` control.

Add one column which represent your Date value (this can be done in designer too)

```
Dim column As New DataGridViewTextBoxColumn With
{
    Header = "Date"
    DataPropertyName = "DATE"
}

yourDataGridView.Columns.Add(column)
yourDataGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = False
```

Then use your DataTable as DataSource

```
yourDataGridView.DataSource = ds.Tables(0)
```

DataGridView will generate rows only for existed data in DataTable.
You can customize "outfit" of DataGridView your needs.

Comment: It seems OP has 10 TextBoxes which needs a text, not only one. You also don't override the old text with String.Empty if there is no row., say at position 10.

Comment: @TimSchmelter - right, updated answer with another approach.